# Can I open the the add event to calendar screen of the IOS calendar app with pre-filled data from my app?

Tags: ios, swift, ekeventkit

I want to add a new event to the IOS calendar, I know this can be done easily using the EventKit. However I do not want to add the event directly, I want the calendar app to be launched with the "add event" screen pre-filled with data passed from my application, as shown in the attached screenshot, and the user can have the option to edit the event details, save the event or cancel it. I know I can launch the calendar app using the "calshow:" NSURL and  UIApplication.shared.open function, however this only opens the day I pass it and not the "add event" screen I would like to open.

I've searched high and low for a way to do it but found nothing.

Any suggestions?

[add event screen to be opened when calendar is launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hne5h.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can use [**EventKitUI**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui) framework for that.

Use **EKEventEditViewController**.

> Presented modally, the event edit view controller provides a way for
>   users to add new events, as well as edit or delete events from their
>   calendar.

Ref : **[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui/ekeventeditviewcontroller)**

For pre-filled values use **event** property.

```
// Create event 
   var store = EKEventStore()
   var event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
   event.title = "Title"
        //event.startDate = startDate
        //event.endDate = currentEvent?.endDate


  let eventViewController: EKEventEditViewController = EKEventEditViewController()
  eventViewController.event = event
  eventViewController.eventStore = store
  eventViewController.editViewDelegate = self

present(eventViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'm gettin an error: "Use of undeclared type 'EKEventEditViewController'" even though I've imported the EventKit library

Comment: Just imported the EventKitUI library and the error is gone, however I'm gettin another error that says: "Cannot call value of non-function type 'EKEventEditViewController'"

Comment: I just realized this is because my class is not of type UIViewController, I changed it ti that and was able to build, however it did not present the eventViewController

Comment: @HannahSaud: Present it from your view controller. updated answer

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. However I cannot edit the date and time, and the add and cancel buttons do nothing. Do I have to handle them manually? if so how do I do that? I checked the functions in EKEventEditViewController but didn't find any related to allowing the editing of dates or adding actions to the cancel and Add buttons.

Comment: I did set it to self. The cancel and edit buttons are still not working

Comment: Got the solution, my class wasn't of type UIViewController so I changed it to that and added this extension:

extension CalendarEvent: EKEventEditViewDelegate {
    
    func eventEditViewController(controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWithAction action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

It's working now, thank you for all your help :)